# jxbrowser -- jquery.AreYouSure .. warning message always in English...

Tags: jxbrowser

i trying to use jquery.AreYouSure into  JxBrowser(5.2 and/or next version). 
jquery.AreYouSure  works... but the warning pop up windows is always in english... 
This behaviour is wrong and differ from chrome/firox/ie.... these  show message in the current language...

this is a demo url

http://www.papercut.com/products/free-software/are-you-sure/demo/are-you-sure-demo.html

Comment: What should we do to reproduce this issue?

Comment: open 
 

i trying to use jquery.AreYouSure into JxBrowser(5.2 and/or next version). jquery.AreYouSure works... but the warning pop up windows is always in english... This behaviour is wrong and differ from chrome/firox/ie.... these show message in the current language...

this is a demo url

http://www.papercut.com/products/free-software/are-you-sure/demo/are-you-sure-demo.html
 into a firefox     modify something and press over goolge link (see attachment 1) you got an alert message  (attachment2) . Then do the same thing in JxBrowser  and you got dirrent  alert. (Attach 3)

Comment: attachment 3 https://www.dropbox.com/s/jmnywmefvmgqp9e/att3.png?dl=0
attachment 2  https://www.dropbox.com/s/5z7f18ikku16u4j/attach2.png?dl=0
attachment 1 https://www.dropbox.com/s/724vrhh66d3zixl/attch1.png?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

By default, JxBrowser displays dialogs configured with English language. At the same time, JxBrowser API provides functionality that allows modifying default behavior and display your own dialogs with required language. To change the language you need to register your own `DialogHandler` where you can display your own dialog. For example:

```
import com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.Browser;
import com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.CloseStatus;
import com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.UnloadDialogParams;
import com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.swing.BrowserView;
import com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.swing.DefaultDialogHandler;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

/**
 * The sample demonstrates how to catch onbeforeunload dialog.
 */
public class BeforeUnloadSample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Browser browser = new Browser();
        final BrowserView view = new BrowserView(browser);

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(view, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.setSize(700, 500);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        browser.setDialogHandler(new DefaultDialogHandler(view) {
            @Override
            public CloseStatus onBeforeUnload(UnloadDialogParams params) {
                String title = "Confirm Navigation";
                String message = params.getMessage();
                int returnValue = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(view, message, title, JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);
                if (returnValue == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION) {
                    return CloseStatus.OK;
                } else {
                    return CloseStatus.CANCEL;
                }
            }
        });
        browser.loadHTML("<html><body onbeforeunload='return myFunction()'>" +
                "<a href='http://www.google.com'>Click here to leave</a>" +
                "<script>function myFunction() { return 'Leave this web page?'; }" +
                "</script></body></html>");
    }
}
```